# android: public static variables being reset across same package in different classes in the framework

Tags: android, variables, frameworks, static

I'm trying to keep track of home key button hit and touch event in the
area of interest pressed within some fixed window of time.
For that I'm using
public static int COUNTER_HOME =0 in View.java under frameworks/base/
core/java/android/view/

I then increment the variable in WindowManagerService.java under
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/
View.COUNTER_HOME++
when i acess the variable upon touch event in ViewGroup.java which is
a subclass of View under frameworks/base/core/java/android/view
I see the COUNTER to be 0,
WHy is that, is the class ViewGroup reloaded everytime the control
transfers from WindowManagerService, I dont understand it or there is
something I'm missing?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Do you create your version of Android framework? I wonder how do you add "public static int COUNTER_HOME =0 in View.java under frameworks/base/ core/java/android/view/" ?

Answer (score 1):

It does not become clear from your description if you set and read the variable from the *same* process. As every process has its own heap, they also have their own, independent copies of the variable.